# Why is sqlite3 not being recognized by VSCode?

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble running sqlite3 in the powershell in VSCode. I already have sqlite3 in my PATH so that is not it. My code is below and seems to be  working just fine and it is properly creating the students.db file. However when I go to access it in the terminal I get this.

PS C:\Users\Devin\Desktop\Intermediate Python> sqlite3 students.db

sqlite3 : The term 'sqlite3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- sqlite3 students.db

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sqlite3:String) [], CommandNotFoundE
    xception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('students.db')


class Student(Model):
    username  = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    points = IntegerField(default=0)
    

    class Meta:
        database = db


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Student], safe=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the path using: `$env:psmodulePath`. Then use Import-Module to import